# Staging Error while Pushing a Spring Application to Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

I am getting the following Error while pushing the Sample Hello World spring application on CloudFoundry.

```
Using manifest file C:\Users\I321571\Desktop\helo\Hello\manifest.yml

Updating app Hello in org trial / space I321571 as I321571...
OK

Uploading Hello...
Uploading app files from: C:\Users\I321571\Desktop\helo\Hello
Uploading 20.1K, 46 files
Done uploading
OK

Stopping app Hello in org trial / space I321571 as I321571...
OK

Starting app Hello in org trial / space I321571 as I321571...
-----> Downloaded app package (12K)
    Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/java-buildpack'...
    -----> Java Buildpack Version: b050954 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#b050954
[Buildpack]                      ERROR Compile failed with exception #<RuntimeError: No container can run this application. Please ensure that you've pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the
-p command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid JVM artifacts can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation. >
No container can run this application. Please ensure that you've pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid JVM artifac
ts can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation.
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

FAILED
Error restarting application: BuildpackCompileFailed

TIP: use 'cf logs Hello --recent' for more information
```

this is my manifest.yml

```
applications:
- name: Hello
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
```

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Have you specifiied the jar file you want to push? Try cf push -p (path to jar file)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error too!
Make sure the command given is valid

```
  cf push {your-app-name} -p {path to your executable jar}
```